# Remove duplicates from comma separated list

Tags: c#

I wrote the following program in C# to remove duplicate elements in a string. However this program is not able to remove duplicate elements in a comma separated string. Can someone please help me as to how can I remove duplicates like 48375 in the below code from a comma separated list.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string inf = "48375 , 36143 , 66516 , 332674 , 107028 , 319546 , 362998 , 324285 , 110470 , 47870 , 17507 , 331420 , 59873 , 19531 , 107100 , 102487 , 97561 , 332674 , 322436 , 348305 , 44900 , 89921 , 41063 , 105962 , 319546 , 80476 , 363510 , 65760 , 344153 , 52328 , 51692 , 101922 , 359192 , 341859 , 37437 , 356670 , 37550 , 91952 , 349196 , 69361 , 52663 , 110705 , 48701 , 99730 , 343144 , 22001 , 66516 , 85782 , 362998 , 324285 , 16487 , 332329 , 352225 , 329868 , 36143 , 48375 , 97871";

        Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Join(" , ", inf.Split(',').Distinct().ToList().ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: because you have space on both side on the second one.

Answer (score 8):

C# is working correctly - your two 48375 you see in your output are indeed distinct (unique) strings.

Your first 48375 is `"48375 "` with a space at the end and your next 48375 is `" 48375 "` with a space at the start and the end. To C# these are very different things

There are a few easy ways to fix this that come to mind, but this is by no means an exhaustive list:

- Split on a string of `" , "` rather than a character of `','` (must use an array of size one string)
- Remove all the spaces before you start,
- split on spaces too (removing empty entries) or
- trim the spaces off each item

Here are those in code:

```
string.Join(" , ", inf.Split(new[] { " , " }).Distinct());

string.Join(" , ", inf.Replace(" ", "").Split(',').Distinct());

string.Join(" , ", inf.Split(new[]{',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Distinct());

string.Join(" , ", inf.Split(',').Select(e => e.Trim()).Distinct());
```

Typically you don't need to do both `ToList()` and `ToArray()` - choose one or the other depending on whether you plan to perform more manipulations like adding/removing items (use `ToList()`) or just have the data as a simple array for some read-only access (use `ToArray()`).

In this case you don't even need to do either - `string.Join` can work on the `IEnumerable<string>` that `Distinct()` returns

Answer (score 1):

Use trim before distinct op.

```
            Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Join(" , ", inf.Split(',').Select(o=>o.Trim()).Distinct().ToList().ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below option -

string uniqIds = string.Join(",", inf.Split(',').Select(o=>o.Trim()).ToList().Distinct());